# How to unpack a variable in a lambda function?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, iterable-unpacking

Given an input tuple, the goal is to produce a dictionary with some pre-defined keys, e.g. in this case, we have an `add_header` lambda and use the unpacking inside when calling the function.

```
>>> z = (2,1)
>>> add_header = lambda x, y: {"EVEN": x, "ODD": y}
>>> add_header(*z)
{'EVEN': 2, 'ODD': 1}
```

My question is, is there way where the unpacking doesn't need to done when calling the `add_header` function?

E.g. I can change avoid the lambda and do it in a normal function:

```
>>> def add_header(input):
...     x, y = input
...     return {"EVEN": x, "ODD":y}
... 
>>> z = (2, 1)
>>> add_header(z)
{'EVEN': 2, 'ODD': 1}
```

Or I could not use the unpacking and use the index of the tuple, i.e. the `z[0]` and `z[1]`:

```
>>> z = (2, 1)
>>> add_header = lambda z: {"EVEN": z[0], "ODD": z[1]}
>>> add_header(z)
{'EVEN': 2, 'ODD': 1}
```

But is there some way to:

- Use the lambda
- Don't explicitly use the indexing in the tuple
- Don't unpack with `*` when calling the `add_header()` function but it's okay to be inside the lambda function.

and still achieve the same `{'EVEN': 2, 'ODD': 1}` output given `z = (2,1)` input?

---

I know this won't work but does something like this exist?

```
z = (2,1)
add_header = lambda x, y from *x: {"EVEN": x, "ODD": y}
add_header(z)
```

Comment: FWIW, an ugly solution I would never use: `lambda t: next({"EVEN": x, "ODD": y} for x,y in [t])`

Comment: FWIW, another ugly solution I would never use: `lambda t: (lambda x, y: {"EVEN": x, "ODD": y})(*t)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `dict()` with `zip()`:

```py
z = (2, 1)
add_header = lambda tpl: dict(zip(("EVEN", "ODD"), tpl))

print(add_header(z))
```

Prints:

```
{'EVEN': 2, 'ODD': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Don't use a named lambda in the first place](/q/38381556/4518341). Use the `def` instead.

P.S. I think there's an argument to be made that lambdas are weak on purpose, to avoid shoehorning them into situations they shouldn't be, like maybe this case, but I don't have citations for that or a strong argument for why unpacking *specifically* shouldn't be possible inside them. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: You're correct for a general case., but not here To ask a minimal question on them, named lambdas are better, than present an actual usage as it will complicate a thing.

Comment: @EirNym Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying, for the sake of OP's example, a named lambda is fine to take the place of an unnamed lambda? To fix up what you wrote, that'd be: *"You're correct for a general case, but not here. To ask a minimal question on lambdas, named lambdas are better than presenting an actual usage as it would complicate things."*

Comment: Yes, I'm saying, that to present a very specific problem named lambda is ok. Otherwise, `map` or other function should be used to provide an example. Functions  has no such restrictions and it's easy to call `func(*args)`. Current case with lambdas is covered by another PEP3113, and your answer is about good practices.